# ContextCompat ANR reports multiple times on firebase

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I got a ANR report on firebase. Its count is increasing and I cannot figure out this since it does not mention anywhere on my code. This is the ANR on firebase console.

```
main (native): tid=1 systid=5789
   at libcore.io.Linux.access(Linux.java)
   at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.access(ForwardingOs.java:72)
   at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.access(BlockGuardOs.java:73)
   at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.access(ForwardingOs.java:72)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$AndroidOs.access(ActivityThread.java:7766)
   at java.io.UnixFileSystem.checkAccess(UnixFileSystem.java:281)
   at java.io.File.exists(File.java:815)
   at android.app.ContextImpl.ensureExternalDirsExistOrFilter(ContextImpl.java:2889)
   at android.app.ContextImpl.getExternalFilesDirs(ContextImpl.java:773)
   at android.content.ContextWrapper.getExternalFilesDirs(ContextWrapper.java:289)
   at androidx.core.content.ContextCompat$Api19Impl.getExternalFilesDirs(ContextCompat.java:847)
   at androidx.core.content.ContextCompat.getExternalFilesDirs(ContextCompat.java:409)
   at androidx.core.content.FileProvider.parsePathStrategy(FileProvider.java:691)
   at androidx.core.content.FileProvider.getPathStrategy(FileProvider.java:635)
   at androidx.core.content.FileProvider.attachInfo(FileProvider.java:416)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:7471)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:6950)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6845)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400(ActivityThread.java:244)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1959)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:236)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7889)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:600)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:967)
```

Any idea how to get rid of this ANR?

Comment: Any thoughts?...

Comment: Any solution found?

Comment: Nope. Still having the ANR

Comment: Bug reported here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/234116801
No workaround or hints for now unfortunately.